# K-vizinhos mais proximos com KD-TREE em c++

Tags: c++

Preciso implementar um algoritmo para encontrar os k-vizinhos mais proximos de um determinado ponto no plano. A maioria do material encontrado na internet estar em ingles, Preciso do algoritmo e a descriçao do funcionamento 
implementei primeiramente a classe point como abaixo:

```
struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(const int &coordx, const int &coordy)
    {
        x = coordx;
        y = coordy;
    }

    int &operator[](int i) // lvalue
    {
        if(i == 0) return x;
        else  return y;
    }
    const int &operator[](int i) const // rvalue
    {
       if(i == 0) return x;
       else  return y;
    }
    bool operator==(const Point &right) const
    {
        if(this->x == right.x && this->y == right.y)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
};
```

A classe no:

```
class KdTreeNo
{
    public:
        KdTreeNo(Point key);
        ~KdTreeNo();


        Point data;
        KdTreeNo *left;
        KdTreeNo *right;
};
```

e por fim a classe KD-TREE:

```
class KdTree
{
    public:
        KdTree(const int &_DIM);
        ~KdTree();
        void insert( Point key) { insertAux(root, key, 0);}
        void print() const   { printAux(root,0);}

        float distance( Point &a, Point &b)
        {
            float dx = a.x - b.x;
            float dy = a.y - b.y;
            return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        }

    private:
        int DIM;
        KdTreeNo *root;

        void insertAux( KdTreeNo *&ptr, Point key, int dim);
        void printAux( KdTreeNo *ptr, int nivel) const ;

};
```

void KdTree::NNAux(KdTreeNo* ptr, int dim, Point& query, float& bestDist)
  {
         if( query == ptr->data){
          bestDist = 0;
          return;
          }
          bestDist = distance(query, ptr->data);
         if( ptr->left == nullptr && ptr->right == nullptr)
            return;

```
     if(query[dim] < ptr->data[dim])
        NNAux(ptr->left, (dim + 1)%DIM, query,bestDist);
     else
        NNAux(ptr->right, (dim + 1)%DIM, query,bestDist);
```

}

Comment: Sem querer ofender nem nada. Mas o stackOverflow é um lugar para tirar dúvidas ( não pedir ajuda para implementação de código).

E assim como dito nesse importantíssimo post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users , você deve procurar por conta própria pela resposta / o que deseja. Só depois de REALMENTE nao conseguir nenhum resultado, deve vir perguntar no stackOverflow.

Comment: E duvida mesmo, o meu codigo estar dando pau, e pode ter certeza que pesquisei no minimo emnuns 100 lugares, nao tenho preguica em pegar implementar, ja virei noites e noite quebrando a cabeca com isso

Comment: Onde está o seu código que implementa o algoritmo?

Comment: meus amigos o meu código estar postado(atualizei), se nao vai ajudar , nao critiquem!

Comment: @AndreLuiz, eu entendo seu sentimento, mas aqui as pessoas que ajudam fazem por pura vontade própria. Ajude-nos mostrando a sua implementação do algoritmo com um código mínimo e completo, assim ajudaremos a tirar suas dúvidas.